# How can I efficiently use join and pivot in my SQL code

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables. The query returned the desired result just the sorting of records. I added Order By but it did not work.

[image]

Result should be:

[image]

I got the result it is just the sorting of records. I want to order by the ID but it is not working.

QUERY:

```
WITH NAMES AS (

   SELECT

      P.NAMES,
      P.CODE,
      Q.NUM_TYP,
      Q.PHONE_NUM
   FROM
      dbo.NAMES P

      INNER JOIN dbo.PHONE Q 
         ON P.ID = Q.ID
      LEFT JOIN DBO.ADDRESS S
         ON P.PRSN_IK = S.PRSN_IK
      WHERE S.ADDR Is Null  

)

SELECT *    
FROM
NAMES    
PIVOT (Max(PHONE_NUM) FOR NUM_TYP IN (WORK, HOME)) R;
```

Appreciate any input. Thanks.

Comment: `I got the result` so your query is working ? If so, please provide sample DDL-DML in form of text(not image) to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

try trhis :

```
select f1.Name, nullif(f1.code, '') Code ,
isnull(f2.phone_num, 'N/A') work_phone_num, isnull(f3.phone_num, 'N/A') home_phone_num
from Names f1
left outer join Phone f2 on f1.id=f2.id and f2.Num_type='WORK'
left outer join Adress f2b on f2.id=f2b.id and f2.num_type=f2b.add_type
left outer join Phone f3 on f1.id=f3.id and f3.Num_type='HOME'
left outer join Adress f3b on f3.id=f3b.id and f3.num_type=f3b.add_type
where f2b.id is null or f3b.id is null
```

Comment: The query is working. I already got the correct result. I just want to sort it by ID. I tried adding order by but it did not sort it.  The query you have is different but thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

given that your query is working, this should work :

```
;WITH NAMES AS (
SELECT
  P.NAMES,
  P.CODE,
  Q.NUM_TYP,
  Q.PHONE_NUM
FROM dbo.NAMES P
  INNER JOIN dbo.PHONE Q 
     ON P.ID = Q.ID
  LEFT JOIN DBO.ADDRESS S
     ON P.PRSN_IK = S.PRSN_IK
  WHERE S.ADDR Is Null  
), PIVOTED 
AS
(
 SELECT *
 FROM NAMES
 PIVOT (Max(PHONE_NUM) FOR NUM_TYP IN (WORK, HOME)) R
)
SELECT * FROM PIVOTED piv
inner join [dbo].[NAMES] nam
on piv.names = nam.names
ORDER BY nam.ID
```

I have included P.ID and wrapped everything under subquery.

Comment: I tried that earlier by putting Order By but it gave an error. I tried yours but still giving an error. Here is the error, Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Columns appeared twice and duplicated. Thanks though.

Comment: @Jenna : Try `SELECT piv.* FROM PIVOTED piv` instead of `*` at the end. Let me know.